# Problem after adding a new database column to a Powerbuilder DataWindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

After adding a new database column to a DataWindow, the DataWindow no longer diaplays in it's Master Form when the program executes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you preview the datawindow in the painter, does the data display?

Comment: Hi Matt, yes the preview of the data works fine. All I'm trying to add is a simple text field (120 char varchar2) to store email addresses.

Comment: I've found that my form has multiple datawindows that rely on the same datasource table. Once I added the column to those datasources the datawindow now displays.  However when i try to retrieve data I get an error "Error in Sharing Data".

Comment: Sharedata requires the same data columns between the shared datawindows.

Comment: Looks like I've found all the shared datawindows now. Thanks again for your help Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Sharedata seems to have been the culprit.